# Why nginx shows servererror(500) and in log files shows failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

This is my nginx.log.errors I have restarted and stopped the running server,
but the error is same

```
2020/02/12 15:41:19 [emerg] 10488#10488: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in 
use)
2020/02/12 15:41:19 [emerg] 10488#10488: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in 
use)
2020/02/12 15:41:19 [emerg] 10488#10488: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in 
use)
2020/02/12 15:41:19 [emerg] 10488#10488: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in 
use)
2020/02/12 15:41:19 [emerg] 10488#10488: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in 
use)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to stop the program already running at port 80. You can find the program binding to port 80 by command `netstat -ltupn`.

Then you can stop the program by `service programname stop` and start Nginx again.

Comment: Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
    tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
    udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*     -

Answer (score 0):

it means nginx or some other process is already using port 80.

You can kill it using:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

And then try restarting nginx again:

```
service nginx start
```